# ios - multiple async call

Tags: objective-c, ios

in the viewWillAppear of a viewController I have an async call, but the issue I have is every time I went to this viewController an async call will be fired even if the old ones are already running so what I need to check if an old call is still fetching data dont do anything if not fire one

I know I can add a property and set it when starting the call to YES and check it when back to the viewController if YES then it is still fetching, NO we can go through another call 
BUT I dont like suck kind of solution

I'm using the ASIHttpRequest to call the server,I'm wondering if I can check something with this 3rd party to know if it is still fetching or not

solution/help would be appreciated
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you use GCD, you can use [`dispatch_once`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html).